# Linux getfacl and setfacl compatibility

Tags: linux, acl, posix

Trying to use `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands to control ACLs to a specific file to enforce security. Wondering if these two commands are standard and if will they be available in most Linux distributions since I've a script that I'm shipping to customers. If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

[Access-control list (ACL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list)
is a basic concept for all file-systems in which it is supported.

You may be sure to find the `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands in all
Linux distributions.

(Just do not try executing them on a too-basic file-system such as FAT32.)